# How can I find the location of a regex match in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I need to write a function that receives a string and a regex. I need to check if there is a match and return the start and end location of a match. (The regex was already compiled by `qr//`.)

The function might also receive a "global" flag and then I need to return the (start,end) pairs of all the matches.

I cannot change the regex, not even add `()` around it as the user might use `()` and `\1`. Maybe I can use `(?:)`.

Example: given "ababab" and the regex `qr/ab/`, in the global case I need to get back 3 pairs of (start, end).

Comment: Looking at Leon's interpretation vs my own you might want to clarify whether the flag corresponds to the /g modifier or any () captures in the regex.

Answer (score 82):

The built-in variables `@-` and `@+` hold the start and end positions, respectively, of the last successful match. `$-[0]` and `$+[0]` correspond to entire pattern, while `$-[N]` and `$+[N]` correspond to the `$N` (`$1`, `$2`, etc.) submatches.

Comment: Note that $+[0] etc. (the "end positions") give the index of the character *following* the match, not the last character of the match itself.

Comment: Wow didn't know that... Perl is so resourceful (Looking at you, PHP ;)

Answer (score 22):

Forget my previous post, I've got a better idea.

```
sub match_positions {
    my ($regex, $string) = @_;
    return if not $string =~ /$regex/;
    return ($-[0], $+[0]);
}
sub match_all_positions {
    my ($regex, $string) = @_;
    my @ret;
    while ($string =~ /$regex/g) {
        push @ret, [ $-[0], $+[0] ];
    }
    return @ret
}
```

This technique doesn't change the regex in any way.

Edited to add: to quote from *perlvar* on $1..$9. **"These variables are all read-only and dynamically scoped to the current BLOCK."** In other words, if you want to use $1..$9, you cannot use a subroutine to do the matching.

Comment: You can use a subroutine to do the match, but you want the captures you'll have to use substr(), @-, and @+ to extract the matches and return them to the user.

Comment: Correct, but that's a particular PITA.

Comment: Your match_positions function returns undef in one of the possible branches and an array in the rest of the cases. Is that really ok?

Answer (score 8):

The pos function gives you the position of the match. If you put your regex in parentheses you can get the length (and thus the end) using `length $1`.  Like this

```
sub match_positions {
    my ($regex, $string) = @_;
    return if not $string =~ /($regex)/;
    return (pos($string) - length $1, pos($string));
}
sub all_match_positions {
    my ($regex, $string) = @_;
    my @ret;
    while ($string =~ /($regex)/g) {
        push @ret, [pos($string) - length $1, pos($string)];
    }
    return @ret
}
```

Comment: this looks totally incorrect.  instead of pos , use pos($string) in all_match_positions, in the other case, match_positions it does not work at all

Comment: The `return if not $string =~ /($regex)/;` gives you not the possibility to call `pos($string)` with correct results.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the deprecated $` variable, if you're willing to have all the REs in your program execute slower.  From perlvar:

```
   $‘      The string preceding whatever was matched by the last successful pattern match (not
           counting any matches hidden within a BLOCK or eval enclosed by the current BLOCK).
           (Mnemonic: "`" often precedes a quoted string.)  This variable is read-only.

           The use of this variable anywhere in a program imposes a considerable performance penalty
           on all regular expression matches.  See "BUGS".
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# search the postions for the CpGs in human genome

sub match_positions {
    my ($regex, $string) = @_;
    return if not $string =~ /($regex)/;
    return (pos($string), pos($string) + length $1);
}
sub all_match_positions {
    my ($regex, $string) = @_;
    my @ret;
    while ($string =~ /($regex)/g) {
        push @ret, [(pos($string)-length $1),pos($string)-1];
    }
    return @ret
}

my $regex='CG';
my $string="ACGACGCGCGCG";
my $cgap=3;    
my @pos=all_match_positions($regex,$string);

my @hgcg;

foreach my $pos(@pos){
    push @hgcg,@$pos[1];
}

foreach my $i(0..($#hgcg-$cgap+1)){
my $len=$hgcg[$i+$cgap-1]-$hgcg[$i]+2;
print "$len\n"; 
}
```