# Perl Regex - Get offset of all the matches instead of one

Tags: regex, perl, match, offset

I want to search a file for a string and then get offsets for all the matches.
The content of file is as below:

```
sometext
sometext
AAA
sometext
AAA
AAA
sometext
```

I am reading this whole file into a string `$text` and then doing a regex match for `AAA` as follows:

```
if($text =~ m/AAA/g) {
    $offset = $-[0];
}
```

**This will give offset of only one `AAA`. How can I get offset of all the matches?**

I know that we can get all matches in an array using syntax like this:

`my @matches = ($text =~ m/AAA/g);`

But I want offset not matched string.

Currently I am using following code to get offsets of all matches:

```
my $text= "sometextAAAsometextAAA";
my $regex = 'AAA';
my @matches = ();

while ($text =~ /($regex)/gi){
    my $match = $1;
    my $length = length($&);
    my $pos = length($`);
    my $start = $pos + 1;
    my $end = $pos + $length;
    my $hitpos = "$start-$end";
    push @matches, "$match found at $hitpos ";
}

print "$_\n" foreach @matches;
```

But is there a simpler way to to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in way to do this in Perl.  But from [How can I find the location of a regex match in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87380/how-can-i-find-the-location-of-a-regex-match-in-perl/87504#87504):

```
sub match_all_positions {
    my ($regex, $string) = @_;
    my @ret;
    while ($string =~ /$regex/g) {
        push @ret, [ $-[0], $+[0] ];
    }
    return @ret
}
```

Comment: But this returns only the position of last match.

Answer (score 3):

You already know that you should use `$-[0]`! Replace

```
while ($text =~ /($regex)/gi){
    my $match = $1;
    my $length = length($&);
    my $pos = length($`);
    my $start = $pos + 1;
    my $end = $pos + $length;
    my $hitpos = "$start-$end";
    push @matches, "$match found at $hitpos ";
}
```

with

```
while ($text =~ /($regex)/gi){
    push @matches, "$1 found at $-[0]";
}
```

That said, I'm a big fan of separating calculations from output formatting, so I would do

```
while ($text =~ /($regex)/gi){
    push @matches, [ $1, $-[0] ];
}
```

PS — Unless you've unrolled a while loop, `if (/.../g)` makes no sense. At best, the `/g` does nothing. At worse, you get incorrect results.