# Computed regular expression replacement in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to do a global regex replace, where the replacement is conditional upon some logic that can't be put in a regular expression. For example:

```
while ( $var =~ /<IF OPERATOR="(.+?)" VALUE="(.+?)"\/>/g ) {
    my $operator = $1;
    my $value = $2;

    if ( $operator eq 'true' && $hash{ $value } ) {
        # replace the entire <IF/>
    }
    if ( $operator eq 'false' && ! $hash{ $value } ) {
        # replace the entire <IF/>
    }
}
```

How do I do the # replace bit? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html `$var =~ s/<IF OPERATOR="(.+?)" VALUE="(.+?)"\/>//;` is this what you mean? Just remove the whole thing?

Comment: it could be helpful if you'll give an example of your replacement. If I understood you `$var =~ s/<IF OPERATOR="$operator" VALUE="$value"\/>/your-replacement/;` doesn't work for your case

Comment: Yes, I want to place the whole thing but only if the logic inside the while {} matches. A simple s/A/B/g; won't work because A is more complicated than I can figure out how to put in a regex. For example the way $hash{ $value } is used. This idea of testing a value captured by the regex is central to what I need to do.

Comment: What I actually replace it with isn't very important to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your refusal to give any real data for this question, or to describe what changes you want, makes it very difficult to demonstrate the workability of a solution.

However it looks like you need an *executable* replacement, which has the `/e` modifier.

Take a look at this code. I have added another pair of parentheses to the regex so that the entire pattern is captured as well as the two attributes. The actual replacement string is put into `$replacement` and returned by the block.

```
$string =~ s{(<IF OPERATOR="([^"]+)" VALUE="([^"]+)"/>)}{

    my $replacement = $1;
    my $operator    = $2;
    my $value       = $3;

    if ( $operator eq 'true' and $hash{$value} ) {
      $replacement = qq{<if state1="yes"/>};
    }
    elsif ( $operator eq 'false' and not $hash{$value} ) {
      $replacement = qq{<if state1="no"/>};
    }

    $replacement;
}eg;
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect - does what I need, and is easy code to follow. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A lot of logic can be placed in regular expressions. For instance, there are [conditional regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Conditional-expressions), and you can [execute Perl code in a regexp](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#A-bit-of-magic%3a-executing-Perl-code-in-a-regular-expression).

If you don't want to complicate the regexp, you can [extract the offsets of the matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439952/perl-regex-get-offset-of-all-the-matches-instead-of-one) first, then splice them out with `substr EXPR, OFFSET, LENGTH, ''`.

But for the fun of using regexps, with [named backreferences](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Named-backreferences) and [s///e](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) (evaluate the replacement), here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my %hash = (
  foo => 1,
  bar => 0
);

my $var = '
<IF OPERATOR="true" VALUE="foo"/>
<IF OPERATOR="true" VALUE="bar"/>
<IF OPERATOR="false" VALUE="foo"/>
<IF OPERATOR="false" VALUE="bar"/>
';

$var =~
  s`(<IF\s+OPERATOR="(?<operator>.+?)"\s+VALUE="(?<value>.+?)"/>)
   `$+{operator} eq 'true' && $hash{ $+{value} } || $+{operator} eq 'false' && !$hash{ $+{value} }? 'replacement' : $1
   `xeg;

print $var;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$var=$ARGV[0];
my %hash =(
a => 1,
b => 2
);
while ( $var =~ /<IF OPERATOR="(.+?)" VALUE="(.+?)"\/>/ ) {
    my $operator = $1;
    my $value = $2;


    if ( $operator eq 'true' && $hash{ $value } ) {
        $var =~ s/<IF OPERATOR="$operator" VALUE="$value"\/>/ReplacemenT/g;
    }
    if ( $operator eq 'false' && ! $hash{ $value } ) {
        $var =~ s/<IF OPERATOR="$operator" VALUE="$value"\/>/RR/g;
    }
}
print "$var\n";
```

on something like `'xxx<IF OPERATOR="true" VALUE="a"/>xxx'` returns xxxReplacemenTxxx

Comment: OP wants to replace *all* occurrences that satisfy the condition (note the `/g` flag), not just one.

Comment: Saw the edit, still not good. You test once if `$var` contains the expression, then replace all occurrences with the particular values found by that first match.

Comment: Nope, still :) The `while` doesn't have a `/g`, so it will only match the first occurrence. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22059337/1269037) for how to solve this problem.

Comment: returned to the OP original `while`.  @Dan Dascalescu can you give me an example where it will not work? It will replace all occurrences matching the conditions with what will be specified in the replacement. If it will be `$hash{ $value }`, result will be a set of different replacements

Comment: it had `/g` somehow it has been lost

Comment: Well, fix the `/g` then. And have true and false values for `a` and `b` in the hash. Now they're both true, which is why you can't see when it will fail. Anyway, try my test case above.

Comment: @Dan Dascalescu yes, you're right this solution will not work for false values in the hash. Yours does work