# Exact pattern match using perl index() function

Tags: perl

I am trying to use the index() function and I want to find the position of a word inside a string, only when it is an exact match. For example:

My string is `STRING="CATALOG SCATTER CAT CATHARSIS"`

And my search string is `KEY=CAT`

I want to say something like `index($STRING, $KEY)` and check match for CAT, and not CATALOG. How do I accomplish this? The documentation says

> The index function searches for one string within another, but without the wildcard-like behavior of a full regular-expression pattern match.

which makes me think that it may not be that straight-forward, but my perl skills are limited :). Is it possible to do what I am trying to do?

Hopefully, I was able to articulate my question well. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You mean `cat` substring should be 'found' only if it has no letters preceding and following it? This is exactly what regexes are for. While it's technically possible to use `index` (checking the symbols before the result position and after the result position + length of key), that's awkward, to say the least.

Comment: You want a regular expression. This question has been [asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87380/how-can-i-find-the-location-of-a-regex-match-in-perl).

Comment: See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
my $str = "CATALOG SCATTER CAT CATHARSIS";
my $key = "CAT";
if ($str =~ /\b$key\b/) {
    say "match at char ",$-[0];;
} else {
    say "no match";
}
```

**output:**

```
match at char 16
```

Comment: Thank you all for the info.
I will use pattern matching instead of index().
(it takes a bit of time to know about right suit at right place ;-) )

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn about [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) in Perl. Perl didn't invent *Regular Expressions*, but tremendously expanded upon the concept. In fact, many other programming languages talk specifically about using *Perl Regular Expressions*.

A regular expression matches a specific word pattern. For example, `/cat/` matches the sequence *cat* in a string.

```
if ( $string =~ /cat/ ) {
    print "String contains the letters 'cat' in a row\n";
}
```

In many ways, this does the same thing as:

```
my $location = index ( $string, "cat" );
if ( $location =! -1 ) {  # index returns -1 when substring isn't found
    print "String contains the letters 'cat' in a row\n";
}
```

But, both of these would match:

- `"Don't let the cat out of the bag"`
- `"The Sears catalog arrived in the mail"`

You don't want to match the last. So, you could do this:

```
 my $location = index $string, " cat ";
```

Now, `index $string, " cat "` won't match the word catalog. Case closed! Or is it? What about:

- `"cat and dog it doth rain."`

Maybe you could check and say things are okay if a sentence starts with "*cat*":

```
if ( (index ($string, " cat ") != -1) or (index ($string, "cat") = 0) ) {
    print "String contains the letters 'cat' in a row\n";
}
```

But, what about these?

- `"The word CAT in all uppercase"`
- `"Stupid cat"`
- `"Cat! Here Cat! Common Cat!"`: Punctuation after the word "cat"
- `"Don't let the 'cat' out of the 'bag'"`: Quotation Marks around "cat"

It could take dozens of lines to specify each and every one of these conditions.

However:

```
if ( $string =~ /\bcat\b/i ) {
    print "String contains the word 'cat' in it\n";
}
```

Specifies each and every one -- and then some. The `\b` says this is a word boundary. This could be a space, a tab, a quote, the beginning or ending of a line. Thus `/\bcat\b/` specifies that this should be the word `cat` and not `catalog`. The `i` on the end tells your regular expression to ignore case when matching, so you'll find `Cat`, `cat`, `CAT`, `cAt`, and all other possible combinations.

In fact, Perl's regular expressions is what made Perl such a popular language to begin with.

Fortunately, Perl comes with not one, but two tutorials on Regular Expressions:

- [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html): Perl Regular Expression Tutorial
- [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html): Perl Regular Expression Quick Start.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very nicely explained. 
Reading this answer can be the first step to enter the world of regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

That's (partial) solution of this problem with `index`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $test = 'CATALOG SCATTER CAT CATHARSIS';
my $key = 'CAT';

my $k_length = length $key;
my $s_length = (length $test) - $k_length;

my $pos      = -1;
while (($pos = index $test, $key, $pos + 1) > -1) {
  if ($pos > 0) {
    my $prev_char = substr $test, $pos - 1, 1;
    ### print "Previous character: '$prev_char'\n";
    next if $prev_char ge 'A' && $prev_char le 'Z'
         || $prev_char ge 'a' && $prev_char le 'z';
  }
  if ($pos < $s_length) {
    my $next_char = substr $test, $pos + $k_length, 1;
    ### print "Next character: '$next_char'\n";
    next if $next_char ge 'A' && $next_char le 'Z'
         || $next_char ge 'a' && $next_char le 'z';
  }
  print "Word '$key' found at " . $pos + 1 . "th position.\n";
}
```

As you see, it's kinda wordy, because it uses basic Perl string functions - `index` and `substr` - only. Checking whether the substring found is indeed a word is done via checking its next and previous characters (if they exist): if they belong to either `A-Z` or `a-z` range, it's not a word.

You can simplify it a bit by trying to lowercase these characters (with lc), then check against the single character range only:

```
my $lc_prev_char = lc( substr $test, $pos - 1, 1 );
next if $lc_prev_char ge 'a' && $lc_prev_char le 'z';
```

... but then again, it's quite a minor improvement (if improvement at all).

Now consider this:

```
my $test = 'CATALOG SCATTER CAT CATHARSIS CAT';
my $key = 'CAT';
while ($test =~ /(?<![A-Za-z])$key(?![A-Za-z])/g) {
  print "Word '$key' found at " . ($-[0] + 1) . "th position.\n";
}
```

... and that's it! The pattern literally tests the string given ($test) for the substring given ($key) not being either preceded with or followed by the symbol of A-Za-z range, and supporting Perl regex magic ([this variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@LAST_MATCH_START), in particular) makes it easy to get the starting position of such substring.

The bottom line: use regexes to do the regexes' work.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions allow for the search to contain word boundaries as well as distinct characters. While

```
my $string = "CATALOG SCATTER CAT CATHARSIS";
index($string, 'CAT');
```

will return zero or greater if `$string` contains the characters `CAT`, a regular expression like

```
$string =~ /\bCAT\b/;
```

will return *false* as `$string` doesn't contain `CAT` preceded and followed by a word boundary. (A *word boundary* is either the beginning or end of the string, or between an word character and a non-word character. A *word character* is any alphanumeric character or an underscore.)

Answer (score -1):

use \E value.
so :

```
#!usr/bin/perl

my $string ="Little Tony";
my $check = "Ton";

if($string =~ m/$check\E/g)
{
print "match";
}
else 
{ 
die("No Match"); 
}
```

Comment: In the OP problem, this should not match, yet it does, because `\E` is not a relevant escape for this purpose. `\E` ends a character modification like preventing metacharacters or changing the case of the string.