# How to print and get index of two regex match in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

How can I print and get index from regex here:

```
my $search1 = "aaaNAMEaaaa";
my $search2 = "bbbbCHECKbbb";

if ( $search1 =~ /na\we/i and $search2 =~ /che\wk/i ) {
    print "String found\n";
    #  This works with one search
    #  my $matched = $&;
    #  my $pos = index( $search1, $matched ); 
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87380

Answer (score 3):

If both expressions match, `$&` will only have the last match. i.e. for the example above `$&` will always have the value `CHECK` and never have `NAME` because it was overwritten by the second pattern match.

You can wrap this logic in a function, then call that function as many times as you'd like with different string, pattern combinations:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $search1 = "aaaNAMEaaaa";
my $search2 = "bbbbCHECKbbb";

print index_from_match($search1, qr/na\we/i), "\n";  #  3
print index_from_match($search2, qr/che\wk/i), "\n"; #  4
print index_from_match($search1, qr/che\wk/i), "\n"; # -1 

sub index_from_match {
    my ($s, $pattern) = @_;

    # uses a capture group instead of $& 
    if ( my ($match) = $s =~ m/($pattern)/ ) {
        return index($s, $match);
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The core problem is that you're doing two regex comparisons in a single expression, so the values for the first one are lost before they can be processed

It's really hard to see how to help you without understanding the program flow within the conditional statement and how you actually use those values

Other languages use the idea of a *match object*, and it's easy to simulate that here by writing a subroutine that returns either a [ string, offset ] pair if the pattern matched, or `undef` if not. It's also less wasteful to use the built-in `@-` and `@+` arrays to provide the values needed instead of repeating the search with `index`

It would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Carp 'croak';


my $search1 = 'aaaNAMEaaaa';
my $search2 = 'bbbbCHECKbbb';

my $match1 = match($search1, /na\we/i);
my $match2 = match($search2, qr/che\wk/i);

if ( $match1 and $match2 ) {

    print "String found\n";

    printf qq{"%s" found at offset %d\n}, @$match1;
    printf qq{"%s" found at offset %d\n}, @$match2;
}


sub match {
    my ($s, $re) = @_;
    croak "Compiled regex required" unless ref $re eq 'Regexp';

    return unless $s =~ $re;

    [ substr($s, $-[0], $+[0]-$-[0]), $-[0] ];
}
```

#### output

```
String found
"NAME" found at offset 3
"CHECK" found at offset 4
```

I think it would also be neater to write this as

```
my $match1 = match($search1, qr/na\we/i);
my $match2 = match($search2, qr/che\wk/i);

if ( $match1 and $match2 ) {

    print "String found\n";

    printf qq{"%s" found at offset %d\n}, @$match1;
    printf qq{"%s" found at offset %d\n}, @$match2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Break your compound `if` into multiple `if` statements

```
my $search1 = "aaaNAMEaaaa";
my $search2 = "bbbbCHECKbbb";

my ($matched1, $matched2, $pos1, $pos2);
if ( $search1 =~ /na\we/i) {
    $matched1 = $&;
    $pos1 = index( $search1, $matched1); 
    if ($search2 =~ /che\wk/i ) {
        print "String found\n";
        $matched2 = $&;
        $pos2 = index( $search2, $matched2); 
        #do whatever you need with $pos1 & $pos2
    } else {
        #reset previously set vars
        undef $matched1;
        undef $pos1; 
    }
}
```

Comment: If so, both `if` conditions should be true i.e `and` and needs to go to `else`. Here, even first `if` is true it won't go to `else`

Comment: @SSh first, "if so"... what?   Second, why would you need to go to  the `else`?  The `else` of the second `if` is only to unset the `$matched` and `$pos1` variables that you set because the first `if` was true.  If the first `if` is false, you haven't set those variables anyway, so they don't need to be unset.

Comment: @SSh: Your comment isn't very clear! It would help enormously if you gave *examples* of how this answer doesn't work for you. If you need to write code then you should [*edit your question*](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37303123/edit) to provide additional information

Comment: I have modified my code and explained what am I doing

Comment: @PaulL I need `elsif` and `else` for first `if`. This is needed for other options. Yes, I haven't set up here but I do have for matching. If I put `elsif` for first `if` even if there are no match in both `if`, its not going to `elsif` but going to else of second `if`. Thanks

Comment: I gave you a way to do what you asked in your question.  Now you're asking a completely different question.  Edit your question to show what you *actually* need to do.