# awk finds first match, not all matches in line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, search, awk

## Background info:

I am trying to search for a pattern (string) in a file. I want to print the line and the position in the line, where the pattern was found.

So far, I am able to find the **first** appearance of the the **first letter** of my pattern.

**But I want to find all occurences of the whole pattern**

## Code (search.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
awk -v s="$2" 'i=index($0, s){print "line: " NR, "pos: " i}' "$file"
```

## Command-line call:

```
$ ./search.sh test.txt GA
```

### test.txt

```
1 GAGAGAGAGA
2 CTCTCTCTCT
3 TATATATATA
4 CGCGCGCGCG
5 CCCCCCCCCC
6 GGGGGGGGGG
7 AAAAAAAAAA
8 TTTTTTTTTT
9 TGATTTTTTT
10 CCCCCCCCGA
```

when I run the above command-line call with test.txt, the result printed is:

### result:

```
line: 1 pos: 1
line: 4 pos: 2
line: 6 pos: 1
line: 9 pos: 2
line: 10 pos: 9
```

which is obviously only the first match of only G.

Is there any way to slightly modify my awk command or am I thinking in a totally wrong direction?

Comment: What's your desired output ?

Comment: line:1 pos:1 line:1 pos:3 line:1 pos:5 etc. I was not precise, I want the line and the starting position of my pattern in the line, and that for all occurences

Comment: It does not have the numbers written there, I wrote them for better understanding of the output.

Comment: @Shushiro, hmmmm it confused me also, I have edited my solution now let me know if that helps you on same.

Comment: @Shushiro: If you've included something in your input file just for explanation then you should clearly mention this in your original question. I'd guessed this time but it confused all the people answering here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following awk may help you in same.

```
cat search.sh
Input_file="$1"
text_to_be_searched="$2"
awk -v var="$text_to_be_searched" '{
while($0){
  match($0,var);
  q=q?q+length(var):RSTART;
  if(RSTART){
    val=val? val "," q:"Line:"NR FS "pos:" q;
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH);
}
  else{
    if(val){
      print val};
    q=val="";
    next
}
};
  print val;
  q=val=""
}
END{
  if(val){
    print val
}}
'   "$Input_file"

./search.sh test.txt GA
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Line:1 pos:1,3,5,7,9
Line:9 pos:2
Line:10 pos:9
```

Answer (score 1):

**With Grep**

**test.txt**

```
GAGAGAGAGA
CTCTCTCTCT
TATATATATA
CGCGCGCGCG
CCCCCCCCCC
GGGGGGGGGG
AAAAAAAAAA
TTTTTTTTTT
TGATTTTTTT
CCCCCCCCGA
```

**search.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    ((++i))
    echo "$line" | grep -bon "$2" | sed -r "s@^([0-9]+):([0-9]+):.*@Line: $i, Position: \2@g"
done < "$1"
```

**Output**

```
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$ bash search.sh test.txt GA
Line: 1, Position: 0
Line: 1, Position: 2
Line: 1, Position: 4
Line: 1, Position: 6
Line: 1, Position: 8
Line: 9, Position: 1
Line: 10, Position: 8
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$
```

**NOTE**

Position index start from zero.

Comment: The OP asked about Awk, not Grep. Its customary to answer the question that was asked before answering questions that were not asked.

Comment: @jww I see the question tagged as linux as well.. there are plenty of ways to solve a problem on command line, I don't see why it should be restricted to awk alone... may be that makes it too broad for SO, but unless new questions are forced to asked on other relevant sites, this will continue... you could try asking it on meta if you want

Comment: @Sundeep - I bite... What is confusing about the title *"awk finds first match, not all matches in line"*; and the Awk tag? How do you make the leap he's ***not*** looking for an Awk related answer to his Awk related question? Good luck with asking on Meta. Stack Overflow readers are not exactly known for their reading comprehension skills or their attention to detail.

Comment: that is purely based on my experience of using command line and answering questions here on SO... some times OP would insist solution only using particular command but mostly OP is just looking to solve a problem using any command and/or shell constructs

Answer (score -1):

With `perl`

```
$ perl -lne 'while(/GA/g){print "line: $. pos: $-[0]"}' ip.txt
line: 1 pos: 0
line: 1 pos: 2
line: 1 pos: 4
line: 1 pos: 6
line: 1 pos: 8
line: 9 pos: 1
line: 10 pos: 8

$ perl -lne 'while(/GA/g){print "line: $. pos: ", $-[0]+1}' ip.txt
line: 1 pos: 1
line: 1 pos: 3
line: 1 pos: 5
line: 1 pos: 7
line: 1 pos: 9
line: 9 pos: 2
line: 10 pos: 9
```

From [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

> $-[0] is the offset of the start of the last successful match
>
> $. Current line number for the last filehandle accessed.

`while(/GA/g)` to iterate over all matches

To pass variable

```
$ s='GAT' perl -lne 'while(/$ENV{s}/g){print "line: $. pos: $-[0]"}' ip.txt
line: 9 pos: 1
```

See also: [How can I find the location of a regex match in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87380/how-can-i-find-the-location-of-a-regex-match-in-perl)