# What is the proper way to get the first separator position for a separator RegExp in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

I try to separate a Text or Token from a text line under Debian Liunx and using perl 5.20. Something like:

```
 RED_123-DASH.DOT: PARAM1 PARAM2 ... MANY MORE
```

Due to a possible large number of arguments after the token separeted by `\s`, I want only the first separator position.  According to the proposed solution [stack.overflow post form Leon Timmermans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/87410/3338646) and [the $-[0] variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/87504/3338646), I adopted the following code for a test:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# Tokens.pl ---  Lead Token Test

use warnings;
use strict;

# Separator pattern for the token
my $TSEP = qr/^\s*[\w\-\.]+(:|\s)/;

# Example text with all ID elements inside 
my $TEXT = '  RED_123-DASH.DOT: PARAM1 PARAM2 ...';

# Subroutine for the test
# $text   - the text to strip the token from
# $global - use the global flag or not
#
# Output:
#  TKN:    Token    if position found
#  SKIP:   Original if no position found 

sub stripToken($$) {
    my ($text, $global) = @_ ;
    my $test = 0;
    $test = $text =~ /$TSEP/g if $global;
    $test = $text =~ /$TSEP/  if not $global;
    if ( $test ) {
        my $pos = pos($text);
        return "SKIP: $text" if not $pos;
        return "TKN:  ". substr($text, 0, $pos-1);
   } else {
       return "ORG:  $text";
   }
}
  
# Test with global flag OK!
print "WITH.GFLAG: ",stripToken($TEXT, 1), "\n";

# Test without global flag NOT OK!
print "NONE.GFLAG: ",stripToken($TEXT, 0), "\n";
```

Leon proposed a `match_positions` sub routine without the `/.../g` flag if you only want the first matching position.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/87410/3338646

```perl
sub match_positions {
    my ($regex, $string) = @_;
    return if not $string =~ /($regex)/; # <----------- pos without /.../
    return (pos($string) - length $1, pos($string));
}

sub all_match_positions {
    my ($regex, $string) = @_;
    my @ret;
    while ($string =~ /($regex)/g) {  # <----------- pos with /.../
        push @ret, [pos($string) - length $1, pos($string)];
    }
    return @ret
}
```

But this does not work.

```
/usr/bin/env perl "Tokens.pl"
WITH.GFLAG: TKN:    RED_123-DASH.DOT
NONE.GFLAG: SKIP:   RED_123-DASH.DOT: PARAM1 PARAM2 ...
```

The only variant works with the `/.../g` flag.

What is the problem with the `/.../` expression ?

Comment: What do you mean "this does not work"? Were you expecting the same result with `/g` and without `/g`? `pos` only works with `/g`, but since you didn't tell us what you are tying to do, I can't be sure if this is your issue or not.

Comment: @Dada Leon avoids the /.../g flag for the first position test (see edit) and get these position and in my code this works not. As you see the rountine skips because $pos is zero and gives back the 'SKIP ' text. Refer to `....if $global` and `... if not $global` in the subroutine and `stripToken(...,1)` and `stripToken(...,0)` for testing.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Also, you still haven't explained what you are trying to do. If the code works with `/g`, why do you want a version without `/g`? If you want a version without `/g`, why are you trying to use `pos` even though it cannot possibly work?

Comment: @Dada I don't understand what you are commenting ..please refer to the Title, to the **first separator position** aspect  and the proposed solution from Leon.

Answer (score 2):

**Lessons learned ..allways test the solutions before use it!**. Despite of having a high answer ranking, the code proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/87410/3338646 for `match_positions` is not working, because `pos($string)` does not works in the `/.../` context.

```perl
# This proposed routine does not work! 
sub match_positions_A {
    my ($regex, $string) = @_;
    return if not $string =~ /($regex)/; # <----------- pos without /.../g
    return (pos($string) - length $1, pos($string)); # <----- don't work
}
```

The correct code is given on post later https://stackoverflow.com/a/87504/3338646 in the question context.

```
# This proposed routine works 
sub match_positions_B {
    my ($regex, $string) = @_;
    return if not $string =~ /$regex/; # <----------- pos without /.../g
    return ($-[0], $+[0]);
}
```

So one possible correct solution for the question is:

```perl
# Subroutine for the test
# $text   - the text to strip the token from
# $global - use the global flag or not
sub stripToken($$) {
    my ($text, $global) = @_ ;
    my $test = 0;
    $test = $text =~ /$TSEP/g if $global;
    $test = $text =~ /$TSEP/  if not $global;
    if ( $test ) {
        my ($offs, $pos) = ($-[0], $+[0]); # <----------- the difference
        return "SKIP: $text" if not $pos;
        return "TKN:  ". substr($text, $offs, $pos-1);
   } else {
       return "ORG: $text";
   }
}
```

with the result:

```sh
/usr/bin/env perl "Tokens.pl"
WITH.GFLAG: TKN:    RED_123-DASH.DOT
NONE.GFLAG: TKN:    RED_123-DASH.DOT
```